# How do I add attributes to a nested XML array using Savon?

Tags: ruby, xml, savon

I am using *savon version 2.2* to call some SOAP services.  For simple services everything is working OK.  However one service has a complex structure like the example below with both repeating groups and attributes on each group:

```
<sch:RequestControl>
<sch:requestID>6989668868</sch:requestID>
</sch:RequestControl>
<sch:InquiryParam>
  <sch:crmParam name="AccountNumber">1234567</sch:crmParam>
  <sch:crmParam name="History">1</sch:crmParam>
</sch:InquiryParam>
```

My current message looks like this:

```
  <RequestControl>
    <requestID>6989668868</requestID>
  </RequestControl>
  <InquiryParam>
    <crmParam>1234567</crmParam>
    <attributes>
      <crmParam>
        <name>AccountNumber</name>
      </crmParam>
    </attributes>
  </InquiryParam>
  <InquiryParam>
    <crmParam>1</crmParam>
    <attributes>
      <crmParam>
        <name>History</name>
      </crmParam>
    </attributes>
  </InquiryParam>
```

The above is produced using this logic:

```
  message = {   :RequestControl =>
                 { :requestID => 6989668868 },

            :InquiryParam =>  [
                { :crmParam =>  { :content! => @account_number } ,
                  :attributes => { "crmParam" => {"name" => "AccountNumber"} }     },

                { :crmParam =>  { :content! => @history } ,
                  :attributes => { "crmParam" => {"name" => "History"} }     } ]
        }
```

I've tried various combinations using `:crmParam =>  { :content! => @account_number, :attributes => {'name'=>'AccountNumber'} }`  and similar based on the savon and gyoku documentation but have run onto a brick wall in getting the XML to format like the example.  I know I can brute force the message by assigning it to `xml` but that makes it difficult to see what's going on.

Can anyone suggest a fix to have the attributes inside the `crmParam` tags?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Savon handles a Ruby array as you'd like, but the following script should give you a better idea what you can do.

```
require 'savon'

c = Savon.client(endpoint: "http://www.example.com",
                 namespace: "urn:ns.example.com",
                 log: true,
                 log_level: :debug,
                 pretty_print_xml: true)

r = c.call(:call,
           :message => { 
                  :InquiryParam => [ 
                         {"crmParam" => 123,
                        :attributes! => { "crmParam" => { "name" => "AccountNumber" }}},
                         {"crmParam" => 456,
                        :attributes! => { "crmParam" => { "name" => "history" }}}
                        ]
                  }
```